# Apache beam python streaming writing hourly avro files files

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, avro, apache-beam

Getting messages from pubsub and then saving it into hourly or other interval files on gcs does not work. The job only writes the files when I shut down the job. Can anyone point me into the correct direction?

```
topic = 'test.txt'
jobname = 'streaming-' + topic.replace('.', '-')

input_topic= 'projects/PROJECT/topics/' + topic

u = Utils()
parsed_schema = u.get_parsed_avro_from_schema_service(
    schema_name=topic,
    schema_repo_url='localhost'
)

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipelineoptions)

messages = p | 'Read from topic: ' + topic >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=input_topic).with_input_types(bytes)

windowed_lines = (
        messages
        | 'decode' >> beam.ParDo(DecodeAvro(), parsed_schema)
        | beam.WindowInto(
                window.FixedWindows(60),
                trigger=AfterWatermark(),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
            )
        )

output = windowed_lines | 'write result' >> WriteToAvro(
    file_path_prefix='gs://BUCKET/streaming/tests/',
    shard_name_template=topic.split('.')[0] + '_' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '_SSSS-of-NNNN',
    schema=parsed_schema,
    file_name_suffix='.avro',
    num_shards=2
)

result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found that writing from an unbounded source into a bounded one is not supported by python sdk yet. So I will have to change to Java sdk for this.

Comment: How did you do in Java? Could you update the anwer with a pseudo solution in Java?